# /bin/cat: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, shell-script, cat

I have 119766 files in a folder. They are CSV files. I want to find out total number of lines of all files.

I'm trying to run following command:

```
cat * |wc -l
```

But the following error occurrs:

> -bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long

How can I do that? Is there any way around this?

One thing I would like to add that total number of lines would be very large.

Comment: do you want the total number of lines for all files, or a count of lines for each individual file?

Comment: The short answer is. You are hitting  MAX_ARG limit.  `ls, cat, mv` and other commands have this limitations. As the error already tells you,  you are providing too many arguments to the `cat` command in this case. Use `getconf -a |grep MAX_ARG` to see the MAX_ARG value that applies to your kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a line-count for each individual file:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | awk '! /^[ 0-9]+[[:space:]]+total$/'
```

I've excluded the total lines because there will be several of them with this many files being processed.  The `find ... -exec ... +` will try to fit as many filenames onto a single command line as possible, but that will be a LOT less than 119766 files....probably only several thousand (at most) per invocation of `wc`, and each one will result in its own independent 'total' line.

If you want the total number of lines in all files combined, here's one way of doing it:

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | 
    awk '/^[ 0-9]+[[:space:]]+total$/ {print $1}' | 
    xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

This prints only the line counts on the total lines, pipes that into `xargs` to get the counts all on one line, then sed to transform the spaces into `+` signs, and then pipes the lot into `bc` to do the calculation.

Example output:

```
$ cd /usr/share/doc
$ find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | 
    awk '/^[ 0-9]+[[:space:]]+total$/ {print $1}' | 
    xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc 
53358931
```

---

##### Update 2022-05-05

It is better to run `wc -l` via `sh`.  This avoids the risk of problems arising if any of the  filenames are called `total`....aside from the total line being the last line of `wc`'s output, there is no way to distinguish an actual total line from the output for a file called "total", so a simple awk script that matches "total" can't work reliably.

To show counts for individual files, excluding totals:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'wc -l "$@" | sed "\$d"' sh {} +
```

This runs `wc -l` on all filenames and deletes the last line (the "total" line) from each batch run by `-exec`.

The `$d` in the sed script needs to be escaped because the script is in a double-quoted string instead of the more usual single-quoted string. double-quotes were used because the entire `sh -c` is a single-quoted string.  It's easier and more readable to just escape one `$` symbol than to use `'\''` to fake embedding a single-quote inside a single quote.

To show only the totals:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'wc -l "$@" | awk "END {print \$1}"' sh {} + |
  xargs | sed -e 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

Instead of using `sed` to delete the last line from each batch of files passed to `wc` via `sh` by `find ... -exec`, this uses `awk` to print only the last lines (the "total") from each batch.  The output of `find` is then converted to a single line (xargs) with `+` characters between each number (sed to transform spaces to +), and then piped into `bc` to perform the calculation.

Just like the `$d` in the sed script, the `$1` in the awk script needs to be escaped because of double-quoting.

Comment: This fail if a file named `total foo`.

Comment: No, it won't.  That's why i used `awk '$2 == "total"'` for an exact match rather than a regexp match.  It will only "fail" on filenames that **exactly match** 'total', and there's really no way around that since `wc` doesn't have options to either exclude totals or print only totals.  I've thought several times over the years that such options would be useful, but they don't exist.

Comment: The exact match is meaningless here. `printf '1 total\n1 total foo\n' | awk '$2 == "total"'` give you two lines.

Comment: hmmm, yes.  i'll change it to `/ total$/` then.  which will still "fail" on filenames that are exactly 'total' but as i said there's no avoiding that.

Comment: It still fail. You can pipe `wc` to other tools to remove the last line. But it still fail with file named `foo\n99999 bar`. It will add `999999` to your result.

Comment: `total` won't be on only the last line when you're dealing with 100000+ files.  There will be one total line per few thousand filenames (depending on how many fit on a command line).  As for pathological cases involving `\n` characters in filenames - anyone who does that has no right to expect anything other than occasional bizarre behavior.  actions have consequences: make stupid filenames, get stupid results.

Comment: I mean pipe `wc` only, not the entire `find` command.

Comment: yes, i assumed that's what you meant - makes no difference.  `find` runs `wc` on multiple files.  each batch of files `wc` is run on will generate a total line.

Comment: That's why I said you should do something like `-exec sh -c 'wc -l "$@" | sed "$d"' {} +`

Comment: You may have thought that, but this is the first time you've suggested anything like it.  I really don't see how it would make any difference, though.  the problem is not find or -exec. the ONLY problem is the fact that `wc` doesn't have an option to either exclude totals or print only totals, combined with the fact that it's possible for a filename to be exactly 'total'.

Comment: Why no difference? Each `wc` invocation have the last line is total line, you excluded it on each `wc` invocation, so your output is only files with their number of lines.

Answer (score 11):

Well, to give that `cat` from the question a new home, this should do:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

It executes a `cat` with the maximum acceptable number of filenames (`+`) again and again and pipes everything to `wc`. If you do not want to traverse subdirectories, a `-maxdepth 1` has to be added to the find command, after the directory.

As an alternative, the `--files0-from` option to GNU `wc` could be used:

```
find . -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | tail -1
```

This option makes `wc` read not the contents but the *filenames* from stdin, separated by null characters. With `-print0`, `find` will print those filenames null-byte separated. As `wc` will still print out line counts for every file, it is advisable to skip everything except the summary line at the end, hence the `tail`.

Both solutions have the advantage that they will work in any locale, whereas @cas' solutions have to be adapted ('total' is 'insgesamt' in German, e.g.).

Comment: This gave `/usr/bin/find: Argument list too long` (ubuntu 18.04 bash). To clarify, it was searching for files in sub-directories, so like `*/*/s*.out`

Comment: @arun The error message comes from the shell, not find. If you use a wildcard pattern like `*/*/s*.out`, your shell will (try to) expand all matching filenames before even invoking `find`, which makes the whole `find` command kind of futile. It is the same problem as in the question. Something like `find . -type f -name "s*.out" -exec ...` will find all files matching `s*.out` in all subdirectories and do something with them. If you need a certain directory depth (e.g. exactly two subdir levels), play with `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options.

Comment: Thx very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you have too many files, you probably don't want the information to go to stdout, so you can do something like this:

```
IFS="\n"; for file in find ./ -type f; do wc -l "$file" >> ~/linecount.txt; done
```

Comment: Hey, folks who are downvoting this suggestion: It would be helpful to know why you think this to be a poor answer so that I can improve it.